# Animating element moving to the beginning/end of a path?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm animating an element along a path, and while the animation works fine I need to be able to animate the element going TO the path, and then along it.

I can't find any examples of ways to do this, should I create an invisible element so I have a target to animate that element to before it starts on the path? If so how could I do that, or is there a better way?

This is my path.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 840 840" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="rg1" cx="0.474" cy="0.472" r="50%">
            <stop offset="5%" style="stop-color:violet;" />
            <stop offset="15%" style="stop-color:indigo;" />
            <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color:blue;" />
            <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:lime;" />
            <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:yellow;" />
            <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:orange;" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;" />
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>

    <g id="spirals" transform="translate(420,420) rotate(270)"
        style="fill:none;stroke-width:6px;stroke-linecap:round;">
        <path id="spiral" style="stroke:url(#rg1);"
            d="M0,0C3.36,0.06,6.6,-2.82,7.07,-7.07C7.66,-11.26,5.28,-16.67,0,-20C-5.18,-23.4,-13.27,-24.43,-21.21,-21.21C-29.13,-18.12,-36.69,-10.51,-40,0C-43.42,10.46,-42.3,23.68,-35.36,35.36C-28.53,47,-15.79,56.71,0,60C15.69,63.43,34.14,60.2,49.5,49.5C64.88,38.98,76.71,21.03,80,0C83.43,-20.92,78.08,-44.6,63.64,-63.64C49.44,-82.74,26.27,-96.74,0,-100C-26.16,-103.45,-55.05,-95.94,-77.78,-77.78C-100.6,-59.88,-116.76,-31.53,-120,0C-123.48,31.43,-113.8,65.49,-91.92,91.92C-70.34,118.47,-36.76,136.79,0,140C36.66,143.5,75.94,131.67,106.07,106.07C136.34,80.79,156.81,42,160,0C163.53,-41.9,149.54,-86.4,120.21,-120.21C91.24,-154.2,47.24,-176.83,0,-180C-47.13,-183.56,-96.85,-167.4,-134.35,-134.35C-172.06,-101.7,-196.86,-52.47,-200,0C-203.55,52.4,-185.28,107.29,-148.49,148.49C-112.14,189.9,-57.74,216.9,0,220C57.63,223.58,117.75,203.14,162.63,162.63C207.77,122.6,236.92,62.97,240,0C243.62,-62.86,220.98,-128.21,176.78,-176.78C133.05,-225.63,68.21,-256.95,0,-260C-68.13,-263.64,-138.65,-238.85,-190.92,-190.92C-243.49,-143.49,-276.98,-73.47,-280,0C-283.66,73.36,-256.71,149.1,-205.06,205.06C-153.94,261.36,-78.71,297,0,300C78.6,303.69,159.56,274.58,219.2,219.2C279.23,164.4,317.02,83.94,320,0C323.72,-83.84,292.44,-170.01,233.35,-233.35C174.84,-297.12,89.21,-337.04,0,-340C-89.07,-343.71,-180.46,-310.32,-247.49,-247.49C-315,-185.31,-357.03,-94.41,-360,0C-363.74,94.33,-328.18,190.91,-261.63,261.63C-195.75,332.86,-99.67,377.06,0,380C99.57,383.76,201.36,346.05,275.77,275.77C350.73,206.2,397.08,104.91,400,0" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's the second time i found your question, but I am unable to catch what you want to achive. Any way there are great js libraries to animate svg, like vivus, anime, or GSAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you need. This is done with SMIL Animation:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 840 840" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <radialGradient id="rg1" cx="0.474" cy="0.472" r="50%">
    <stop offset="5%" style="stop-color:violet;" />
    <stop offset="15%" style="stop-color:indigo;" />
    <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color:blue;" />
    <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:lime;" />
    <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:yellow;" />
    <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:orange;" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;" />
    </radialGradient>
    </defs>

    <g>
    <path id="spiral" style="fill:none;stroke:url(#rg1);stroke-width:6px;stroke-linecap:round" d="m 420,420 c 0.06,-3.36 -2.82,-6.6 -7.07,-7.07 -4.19,-0.59 -9.6,1.79 -12.93,7.07 -3.4,5.18 -4.43,13.27 -1.21,21.21 3.09,7.92 10.7,15.48 21.21,18.79 10.46,3.42 23.68,2.3 35.36,-4.64 C 467,448.53 476.71,435.79 480,420 c 3.43,-15.69 0.2,-34.14 -10.5,-49.5 -10.52,-15.38 -28.47,-27.21 -49.5,-30.5 -20.92,-3.43 -44.6,1.92 -63.64,16.36 -19.1,14.2 -33.1,37.37 -36.36,63.64 -3.45,26.16 4.06,55.05 22.22,77.78 17.9,22.82 46.25,38.98 77.78,42.22 31.43,3.48 65.49,-6.2 91.92,-28.08 C 538.47,490.34 556.79,456.76 560,420 563.5,383.34 551.67,344.06 526.07,313.93 500.79,283.66 462,263.19 420,260 378.1,256.47 333.6,270.46 299.79,299.79 265.8,328.76 243.17,372.76 240,420 c -3.56,47.13 12.6,96.85 45.65,134.35 32.65,37.71 81.88,62.51 134.35,65.65 52.4,3.55 107.29,-14.72 148.49,-51.51 C 609.9,532.14 636.9,477.74 640,420 643.58,362.37 623.14,302.25 582.63,257.37 542.6,212.23 482.97,183.08 420,180 357.14,176.38 291.79,199.02 243.22,243.22 194.37,286.95 163.05,351.79 160,420 c -3.64,68.13 21.15,138.65 69.08,190.92 47.43,52.57 117.45,86.06 190.92,89.08 73.36,3.66 149.1,-23.29 205.06,-74.94 C 681.36,573.94 717,498.71 720,420 723.69,341.4 694.58,260.44 639.2,200.8 584.4,140.77 503.94,102.98 420,100 336.16,96.28 249.99,127.56 186.65,186.65 122.88,245.16 82.96,330.79 80,420 76.29,509.07 109.68,600.46 172.51,667.49 234.69,735 325.59,777.03 420,780 514.33,783.74 610.91,748.18 681.63,681.63 752.86,615.75 797.06,519.67 800,420 803.76,320.43 766.05,218.64 695.77,144.23 626.2,69.27 524.91,22.92 420,20"/>
    </g>
    <g><path style="fill:#ff0000" d="m 10,-50 30,0 c 5.54,0 10,4.46 10,10 l 0,30.0000001 C 50,-4.459999 45.54,0 40,0 L 10,0 C 4.46,0 0,-4.459999 0,-9.9999999 L 0,-40 c 0,-5.54 4.46,-10 10,-10 z"/>
    <animateMotion id="animateMotion12-8" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="15s" path="m 420,420 c 0.06,-3.36 -2.82,-6.6 -7.07,-7.07 -4.19,-0.59 -9.6,1.79 -12.93,7.07 -3.4,5.18 -4.43,13.27 -1.21,21.21 3.09,7.92 10.7,15.48 21.21,18.79 10.46,3.42 23.68,2.3 35.36,-4.64 C 467,448.53 476.71,435.79 480,420 c 3.43,-15.69 0.2,-34.14 -10.5,-49.5 -10.52,-15.38 -28.47,-27.21 -49.5,-30.5 -20.92,-3.43 -44.6,1.92 -63.64,16.36 -19.1,14.2 -33.1,37.37 -36.36,63.64 -3.45,26.16 4.06,55.05 22.22,77.78 17.9,22.82 46.25,38.98 77.78,42.22 31.43,3.48 65.49,-6.2 91.92,-28.08 C 538.47,490.34 556.79,456.76 560,420 563.5,383.34 551.67,344.06 526.07,313.93 500.79,283.66 462,263.19 420,260 378.1,256.47 333.6,270.46 299.79,299.79 265.8,328.76 243.17,372.76 240,420 c -3.56,47.13 12.6,96.85 45.65,134.35 32.65,37.71 81.88,62.51 134.35,65.65 52.4,3.55 107.29,-14.72 148.49,-51.51 C 609.9,532.14 636.9,477.74 640,420 643.58,362.37 623.14,302.25 582.63,257.37 542.6,212.23 482.97,183.08 420,180 357.14,176.38 291.79,199.02 243.22,243.22 194.37,286.95 163.05,351.79 160,420 c -3.64,68.13 21.15,138.65 69.08,190.92 47.43,52.57 117.45,86.06 190.92,89.08 73.36,3.66 149.1,-23.29 205.06,-74.94 C 681.36,573.94 717,498.71 720,420 723.69,341.4 694.58,260.44 639.2,200.8 584.4,140.77 503.94,102.98 420,100 336.16,96.28 249.99,127.56 186.65,186.65 122.88,245.16 82.96,330.79 80,420 76.29,509.07 109.68,600.46 172.51,667.49 234.69,735 325.59,777.03 420,780 514.33,783.74 610.91,748.18 681.63,681.63 752.86,615.75 797.06,519.67 800,420 803.76,320.43 766.05,218.64 695.77,144.23 626.2,69.27 524.91,22.92 420,20"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I was literally just in the process of responding to your comment to tell you I found a solution, I posted an answer so you could understand what I was trying to do now that I figured it out. Sorry that you spent the time to do that when I already had a solution but yes that is exactly what I was trying to do. So you defined the absolute coordinates of where the path would start? Because my problem was my entire path was in one div, and the element started inside of another div.

Comment: And since my page needs to be responsive I didn't want to define absolute coordinates. Or would that still work if there were several elements that moved and changed relative to each other? If I explained that clearly? If you resized a page of flexbox type elements would that work still without having to redefine the path?

Comment: If what you want to achieve is the animation tha I produced, you don't need to worry about that because everything is inside the svg cordinates system and it won't be affected or will affect the responsiveness of your page. it's a simpler no js solution.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I'll keep that in mind next time I need to do something similar, though I'll probably stick with what I have for now so I don't have to keep switching libraries.

Comment: Every thing is here **<animateMotion rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="15s" path=""/>** where the path for the red rect to follow is an exact copy of the spiral

Comment: As you please, but my solution needs no js libraries. It just works out of the box. Copy the svg from the snippet and try it out on your browser.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware, I assumed it was the name of a separate library. I'm researching it now, that's good to know. Thank you again. I'll start learning about it.

Comment: Consider up voting my answer if it fits your need and acomplish with the goal of the better code is the simplest code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a solution. I wanted to animate an element along a path, but the element doesn't start exactly where the path begins. In my example the path starts on the top-middle side of the container, but the element is closer to the top-left side of the container. This moves an element toward the top-middle side, then starts the animation along the path once the element reaches it.

The code could be adapted to other similar situations. I'm sure there are better ways but I've gone through the GSAP and anime.js libraries and couldn't find a way to do it without the Flip plug-in from GSAP which is under the paid license.

```
let element_position = element.getBoundingClientRect()
let path_container_position = path_container.getBoundingClientRect()
let tl = gsap.timeline()

tl.to(element, {
  x: path_container_position.left - element_position.left + (path_container_position.width / 2) - (element_position.width / 2),
  y: path_container_position.top - element_position.top - (element_position.height / 2),
  ease: 'none',
  duration: 5,
})

tl.to(element, {
  motionPath: {
    path: path_container,
    align: path_container,
    alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
  },
  ease: "power4.easeInOut",
  duration: 10,
  yoyo: true,
  repeat: -1,
})
```

Comment: But it's too much to use two js libraries to acomplish just a simple task. Look at my answer and you will see how easy it is, well if it's what you really want to achieve. Playing around with the start of the spiral path the animation can be reversed.

Comment: Oh I'm not using two libraries. I used GSAP then switched to anime.js when I couldn't find a solution, then went back to GSAP when I couldn't find any libraries that had a built-in way to do it without paying for a license. I tries reversing the path in Illustrator but somehow broke it in the process, so in my actual code (I edited it in my answer to make it more universal) I'm starting it at 1 and going backward.